# Linking multiple social accounts into one app

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, windows-phone-8.1

Before starting, I know that the questions's scope may be too broad but I think that discussing strategies fits this site.

Getting to the point, I'd like to build a mobile app that pulls data from various social networks.

This, of course, requires me to be able to log into each service and have an API/library that works with my platform, which is *Windows Phone 8.1*, unless everything's done online by some service.

I'm thinking to how to make everything work and I came up with two ideas:

- Import and use a .NET library/wrapper to connect and work with the service directly on user's device.
- Create an *Azure Mobile Service* which allows users to create an account for my app and link it to each of their social networks, working with the services online and making my app deal just with my *AMS*.

This is the current situation for the social networks that I'd like to use:

```
+----------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Social Network |          Windows Phone          |                               Azure                                |
+----------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Facebook       | http://facebooksdk.net/         | login supported                                                    |
| Twitter        | http://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/  | login supported                                                    |
| Instagram      | http://instasharp.org/          | not supported                                                      |
| Foursquare     | SharpSquare can be adapted      | https://gist.github.com/rfaisal/9899185#file-login-js may work (?) |
| Flickr         | https://flickrnet.codeplex.com/ | not supported                                                      |
+----------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, while the *Windows Phone* seems the best one, this will force me to deal with different login workflows and can give problems if the APIs of one of the service change because I will need to update the app and make it work with the new APIs, assuming that the developers behind those libraries decide to update them too!

Using *Azure* will only require a single server side update, making it easier to manage, and it will also help with managing user's heterogeneous data because I can parse them online and I can return them in a format which is common between all the services (reducing the bandwidth used by the device to download useless stuff which is included in the services' APIs).

I also looked into something else and I discovered *Auth0* which seems a good service but they don't support *Foursquare*/*Flickr* and the free account is too limited.

The other cool service that I found is https://intridea.github.io/omniauth/

To be honest, I have A LOT of doubts on both the ways that I thought and this leads us to the real question(s):

Given that all the services that I want to use are based on *oAuth2*+*REST* APIs, how would you make this work? Is it better to have everything done server side or it's ok to make the same app login to every server directly on the device? Despite your choice, how would you save the user's logins?

Since this question is open to a lot of different kind of answers, I'll upvote each useful answer and I'll accept the one that gives me the easier scenario to work with.